# Why can't I see the Script Library template in Visual C# Express 2010, after installing script#?

Tags: script#, visual-c#-express-2010

According to the Script# website (http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp), "You can also use Visual C# Express."

I've installed ScriptSharp.msi, but when I open Visual C# Express, I can't find the "Script Library" template.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try Visual Web Developer Express... looking to consolidate installer work and web developer express offers the functionality in C# Express, plus has web app project support as well, which is generally interesting as the generated scripts are mostly used in the context of web apps.

That said, this is really just a templates thing. You should be able to open up an existing project in C# express.

Comment: Hi NikhilK.  Thanks for this.  I installed Visual Web Developer Express, but still cannot find the template.  Do I need to re-install Script# to see it?

Comment: yes, the installer can only install once you have the shell installed.